# Vue passing multiple props

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I am building a website using the PHP framework Laravel. I want to created a vue component that will be used for creating and editing a record. I have gotten this to work with passing one property to the vue component, but now I want to pass a second component to set the text of the button. Maybe there is a better way to do this but let me show you what I have so far

Blade file

```
<addeditshow :show="{{$show}}" :buttonText="Edit"></addeditshow>
```

Note the code above breaks because it does not like I and sending a second parameter

Here is my vue component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" :value="show.name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">Number</label>
            <input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" :value="show.number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="date" name="airDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick a Date" :value="show.airDate">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="podcast">Podcast URL</label>
            <input type="text" id="podcast" name="podcastUrl" class="form-control" :value="show.podcastUrl">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ buttonText }}</button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.show);
        },

        props: {
            show: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Not sure exactly what I am missing. If there is a link to a doc I can read please share.

Comment: I think there is again issue with mustaches, because Laravel uses same as Vue, and you want to pass value down - so I think you don't need binding here, so go without `:`
`<addeditshow show="{{$show}}" :buttonText="Edit"></addeditshow>`

Comment: So the colon in front is all I need?

Comment: Nope colon is shorthand for v-bind, you have to remove it from show attribure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you're saying you could use [`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Single-Slot).

In your component template do this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><slot></slot></button>
```

and when you initialize component in blade do this:

```
<addeditshow :show="{{$show}}">Edit</addeditshow>
```

or if you want it to be dynamic you can do this:

```
<addeditshow :show="{{$show}}">@{{ $buttonText }}</addeditshow>
```

Vue 2 supports even named slots.

Didn't test it but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your dynamic, camelCase attribute `:buttonText` to kebab-case `:button-text`. I had the same problem and was trying to figure it out for a few hours.

> Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and camelCased props need to use their kebab-case equivalents when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "var-val" instead of "varVal".

I'm using Vue 2 and Laravel 5.6.